# How do I display the equation?

Tags: java, equation, multiplication

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Practice {
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.0000"); 
        float myfloat1 =0;
        float myfloat2 =0;
        float myfloat3 =0;
        float myfloat4 =0;
        float result =0; 
        result = (myfloat1 * myfloat2)/(myfloat3 + myfloat4); 

        System.out.println("Please enter first multiplied number");
        myfloat1 = console.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Please enter second multipled number");
        myfloat2 = console.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Please enter first addition number");
        myfloat3 = console.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Please enter second addition number");
        myfloat4 = console.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Your end result is " + df.format(result));
    }
}
```

> Please enter first multiplied number
>   1
>   Please enter second multipled number
>   1
>   Please enter first addition number
>   1
>   Please enter second addition number
>   1
>   Your end result is ?

I'm also getting a question mark at the end. The problem I currently have is not being able to display the equation and the numbers the user assigns. Such as (1*1)/(1+1) and show the result of it. With 4 decimal precision.

Comment: Yeah, you do the math before you even take in the numbers. If you want to print out the inputs, just print them out and format them into the equation. What's the problem? What's stopping you from doing this? I also strongly suspect you're getting an exception `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`, I don't see how you're dividing by zero and NOT getting an exception.

Comment: I feel so dumb, Thank you. I don't know why I did it with the declared variables.@ozi @tnw

Comment: @ParmanandPhaskanram ;) It happens

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.0000");

    float myfloat1 = 0;

    float myfloat2 = 0;

    float myfloat3 = 0;

    float myfloat4 = 0;

    float result = 0;



    System.out.println("Please enter first multiplied number");

    myfloat1 = console.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("Please enter second multipled number");

    myfloat2 = console.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("Please enter first addition number");

    myfloat3 = console.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("Please enter second addition number");

    myfloat4 = console.nextFloat();
    result = (myfloat1 * myfloat2) / (myfloat3 + myfloat4);

    System.out.println("Your end result is " + df.format(result));

}
```

Output is;

```
Please enter first multiplied number
1
Please enter second multipled number
1
Please enter first addition number
1
Please enter second addition number
1
Your end result is 0,5000
```

Answer (score 0):

You did the calculation well before you had the floats from user.

You want to move around your statement that does calculation. So remove your statement like:

```
result = (myfloat1 * myfloat2) / (myfloat3 + myfloat4);
```

And move it to place where you have all the number from user and then print whatever you want like:

```
result = (myfloat1 * myfloat2) / (myfloat3 + myfloat4);
System.out.println("Your end result for (" + myfloat1 + "*" + myfloat2 + ") / (" + myfloat3 + "  + " + myfloat4 + ") is " + df.format(result));
```

Comment: Thank you. I can now do my other programming homework with this help. I wasn't 100% how to show the values.